# What does "turn-over tops" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

yourdictionary.com's definition for shoe top is

> The upper surface of a shoe.

but how are tops turned over? If it was the shoe tongue it would make more sense.

Here is the context:

> The master of the establishment was in another room, but he frequently came down some steps into the main room, his jaunty, tarred boots with red turn-over tops coming into view each time before the rest of his person.

Comment: Source of the quote please!!

Comment: Boots are not shoes.

Comment: @KateBunting an assertion like that requires proof that boots are nothing but very high-top shoes.

Comment: @RonJohn I thought the OP might have been able to work out that, though shoes don't have tops that can 'turn over', boots often do.

Comment: @JamesK It's from Chapter 2 of *Crime and Punishment* by Fyodor Dostoyevsky (Constance Garnett's translation).

Comment: I agree with Kate Bunting on this. The question only comes up because the OP has mentally imaged *shoes* instead of boots.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a pair of boots with turn-over tops. The top of the leg of the boot is turned back, and folded down.  Here the turn-overs are black, to match the rest of the boot.  But it is possible for the turn-over to be dyed red, which would look flamboyant and "jaunty".

[image]
([source](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Gorgeous-Black-Leather-Turnover-Tops-Heeled-Boots-CLARKS-Size-5-5-D-Fit-/202791262943))

In this, "google image search" is your friend.  You can search and find pictures of most things, including phrases that are not found in the dictionary.

Comment: I would never have thought to call those "turn *over* tops", thinking of them as "turn *down*  tops".

Comment: Yes, that would work also, but the translator of Dostoevsky thought differently.

Comment: Naturally, I'm right, and the translator is wrong.  Probably a damned Yankee who thinks that "y'all" is spelled "ya'll" and that it's singular.

Comment: I think this is from the Constance Garnett translation. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constance_Garnett  Born in England, in Brighton, studied Classics at Newnham College Cambridge....

Answer (score 10):

'Puss in Boots' in the famous children's story is very often shown wearing boots with turn-over tops. 17th century period.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It means that he’s folded the top of his boots down/folded them over the top.